# How is “talk past each other” translated into Spanish?

Tags: traducción

Primero mi pregunta en español:

**¿Cómo se traduce “talk past each other” al español?**

---

**Details in English:**

I've been trying, in vain, to find a good way of translating into Spanish the phrase

### talk past one another

as in

[**“Ever feel conservatives and liberals talk past each other and don't really communicate?”**](https://villages-news.com/the-politics-of-division/)

[**“We just quit listening or we talk past each other.”**](http://www.foxnews.com/opinion/2017/10/08/for-human-connections-that-matter-focus-on-things-that-are-excellent-and-worthy-praise.html)

[**“We talk past each other instead of to each other.”**](https://www.desertsun.com/story/opinion/contributors/valley-voice/2018/02/22/flux-and-discomfort-we-must-not-fear-hard-questions/365586002/)

[**“Instead, happily ensconced in our own confirmation-bias bubbles, we merely talk past each other.”**](http://www.pennlive.com/opinion/2017/09/beyond_surviving_trump_--_can.html)

I thought it was a relatively new phrase sparked by the phenomenon created when someone posts comment after comment without listening and/or responding to those commenting in response or doing so in delayed fashion.  (If you've ever even just texted with someone who thinks and texts faster than you do, you know what I'm talking about.)  Well, it turns out that the phrase isn't so new after all and that [**there's even a Wikipedia page on it.**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talking_past_each_other)  Trouble is, it hasn't been translated into Spanish and I've had a difficult time trying to figure out what would be some good translations of it, since it appears that even those who are familiar with the phrase in English may have different notions of what it is.  I have thought about translating it simply as

### hablando pasado uno al otro

but I sense this does not have the same meaning in Spanish and, furthermore, I don’t know that it makes much sense at all.  During the course of any given day, I may come across several combinations of words that don’t have an exact equivalent in Spanish or vice versa, but usually an easy alternative comes to mind or it just isn’t a phrase I see myself using very often.  But this is a phrase that is likely to come up again, and is one that describes a type of behavior that I’m fairly certain is rather universal, so I have more of a vested interest in finding a good translation of it and couldn’t think of a better place to find it than here at Spanish StackExchange.  So, what do you think?  Any suggestions for this phrase?

---

**Detalles en español:**

He estado tratando de encontrar, en vano, una buena manera de traducir al español la frase:

### talk past one another

como en

[Véanse arriba.]

Pensé que era una frase relativamente nueva provocada por el fenómeno creó cuando alguien publica comentario tras comentario sin escuchar y/o responder a los que están comentando en respuesta o hacerlo de manera retardada.  (Si alguna vez sólo has intercambiado mensajes con alguien por textos y la otra persona piensa y escriba más rápido que tú, sabes de que estoy hablando.)  Bueno, ha resultado que la frase no es tan nueva después de todo y que [**incluso hay una página de Wikipedia en este tema.**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talking_past_each_other)  El problema es, la página no ha sido traducida al español y me ha costado tratando de averiguar qué serían algunas buenas traducciones de ella desde que parece que incluso aquellos que están familiarizados con la frase en inglés podrían tener diferentes nociones de lo que es.  He pensado en traducirlo simplemente como:

### hablando pasado uno al otro

pero siento que ésta no tiene el mismo significado en español y, además, no sé que tiene sentido en absoluto.  Durante el curso de cualquier día, puedo encontrarme varias combinaciones de palabras por las que no tenga un equivalente exacto en español o viceversa, pero normalmente una alternativa fácil viene a la mente o simplemente no es una frase que pueda verme usándolo muy a menudo.  Pero ésta es una frase que pueda volvió a aparecer, y es una que describe un tipo de comportamiento que estoy casi segura de que es bastante universal, así que tengo más de un interés personal en encontrar una buena traducción de ella y no podía pensar en un sitio mejor que aquí en Spanish StackExchange.  Entonces, ¿qué piensas?  ¿Algunas sugerencias para esta frase?

Comment: No sé si habrá una expresión totalmente equivalente pero lo más parecido que conozco es [diálogo de sordos](http://dle.rae.es/?id=DetWqMJ#DBrEswk)

Comment: @blonfu "[diálogo de sordos](http://dle.rae.es/?id=DetWqMJ)" = "conversación en la que los interlocutores no se prestan atención". Diría que es una respuesta perfectamente válida.

Comment: @Charlie me parecía poco información para una respuesta pero intentaré redactarlo

Comment: @blonfu basta con que pongas el enlace, la definición, y traduzcas los ejemplos: "En vez de eso, como cada uno estaba encerrado en su burbuja de auto-convencimiento, acabamos teniendo un diálogo de sordos."

Comment: Just as an aside, note how the clumsiness of the literal Spanish translation stems from the different [verb framing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verb_framing) strategies of Spanish and English.

Comment: Very interesting, @pablodf76.  I just now visited the link you included in your comment.  It really opened my mind in terms of one of the ways in which Spanish is structured differently than English.  Thank you for including it!

Answer (score 7):

Primero pensé en «diálogo de besugos» pero es más bien una conversación sin pies ni cabeza donde cada uno habla de cosas distintas y no termina de encajar con el significado de la expresión en inglés pero hay otra expresión con un significado bastante similar que podemos encontrar en el DLE:

> **[diálogo de sordos](http://dle.rae.es/?id=DetWqMJ#DBrEswk)**
>
> 1. m. Conversación en la que los interlocutores no se prestan atención.

Las frases de los ejemplos podrían quedar más o menos así:

> 1. ¿Nunca has sentido que los conservadores y los liberales mantienen un diálogo de sordos y realmente no se comunican?
> 2. Simplemente nos dejamos de escuchar, fue un diálogo de sordos.
> 3. Fue un diálogo de sordos en lugar de un diálogo.
> 4. En vez de eso, como cada uno estaba encerrado en su burbuja de
>    auto-convencimiento, acabamos teniendo un diálogo de sordos. (Esta traducción es de [@Charlie](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/25873/how-is-talk-past-each-other-translated-into-spanish#comment42520_25873))

Comment: No sé si *diálogo de sordos* es una expresión muy habitual, pero *hacer oídos sordos*, que está muy relacionada, sí que lo es. Para los ejemplos de la pregunta, de todos modos, funciona mucho mejor tu propuesta.

Comment: Me parece que tiene algún uso, al menos en libros: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=di%C3%A1logo+de+sordos%2Co%C3%ADdos+sordos&year_start=1800&year_end=2010&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdi%C3%A1logo%20de%20sordos%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Co%C3%ADdos%20sordos%3B%2Cc0

Comment: I am not sure this is quite right. We do have dialogue of the deaf in English (where nobody listens) but talking past one another is more about the situation where we hear but fail to understand, we miss the point. We also have talking at cross purposes with a similar meaning. Obviously Anglophones spend a lot of time failing to communicate to have so many phrases for it.

Comment: I like your answer a lot blonfu, but I agree with @mdewey in that it doesn't completely convey the meaning(s) involved with "talking past one another." The other problem I have with it, is that "talking past one another" often can sometimes involve an _inability_ to understand what another is saying rather than _intentional disregard_. This then leads me to wonder how the hearing impaired feel about language like this because I've met people who are deaf, and though I was unable to communicate very well with them, it was clear they were good communicators among those who spoke their language.

Comment: @blonfu  Don't get me wrong, I'm not trying to be the PC police.  Certainly, your suggestion is better than the one I came up with -- hablando pasado uno al otro -- if, for no other reason than that I would be somewhat understood with the phrase you suggested.  More than that, others seem to like your answer.  Still, I can't help but wonder if others (say those in the Spanish language news business -- journalists, political dialogue hosts, and the like) haven't come up with something that more closely mirrors a situation in which interlocutors are "talking past one another."

Comment: @blonfu  I'm still digesting the content of those who took the time to answer my question via an answer or comment, but yours is a strong contender for la marca verde.  I'd like to let this simmer a bit, though, before taking the pan off the burner, just to see what others might come up with.  In the meantime, gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: @LisaBeck It's possible  this expression doesn't have exactly the same meaning as "talking to each other", but it is the closest thing I found. Maybe it could be translated in other ways by saying something like: _"Hablamos entre nosotros pero no nos entendíamos"_ or _"Parecía que hablábamos en chino, no podíamos entendernos"_

Answer (score 4):

Por dar una alternativa, acabo de encontrar en el diccionario la siguiente expresión:

> **[es hablar por demás](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JvzNhyI#9KaDLd4)**
>
> 1. expr. Denota que es inútil lo que alguien dice, por no hacer fuerza ni impresión a la persona a quien habla.

Es decir, se usa cuando una persona por mucho que hable (y por más razón que tenga) es incapaz por el motivo que sea de impresionar a aquel que le escucha. En este caso, tus ejemplos podrían quedar así:

> ¿No crees que los conservadores y los liberales lo único que hacen es hablar por demás, sin comunicarse?
>
> O paramos a escuchar o simplemente hablamos por demás.
>
> Nos dedicamos a hablar por demás en vez de con los demás.
>
> En vez de eso, como cada uno se escondía feliz en su burbuja de auto-convencimiento, aquello fue simplemente hablar por demás.

Eso sí, reconozco que algunos ejemplos quedan un poco forzados, y tampoco es que haya encontrado muchos ejemplos de la expresión (en el CORDE solo hay uno y tampoco me convenció mucho). Posiblemente no se entienda apenas si la usas, puede que dependa de la región, pero existir existe así que la incluyo como respuesta.

Comment: @walen sí, de hecho iba buscando esa expresión pero no está registrada y encontré esta en su lugar.

Comment: no creo que tenga traduccion o forma en el español, lo mas cercano es "se hablan pero no se escuchan"

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example sentence from special education advocacy (something I spend a lot of time thinking about):

> They attempted mediation but all they did was talk past each other.

A translation of this could start with:

> Fueron a la mediación pero...

Brainstorming, the continuation could be:

> No hacían caso el uno al otro.
>
> Hacían caso omiso el uno al otro.
>
> Era como si no hablaran el mismo idioma.
>
> No ponían atención a lo que el otro decía.
>
> No se escuchaba el uno al otro.
>
> Cada quien hablaba de lo suyo [sin fijarse en lo que decía el otro].

But I think a simple description might be better:

> Muchas palabras, poca comunicación.
>
> Mucho hablar, poco captar.

*If you'd like any of these constructions explained, let me know.*